# py2exe [ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy]

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, py2exe

I installed sqlalchemy-0.8.1 in my win7 via 'setup.py install'

and "import sqlalchemy" works well

But when I want to pack my files with py2exe, error occurs

ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy

Here is part of my setup.py

```
import os
import glob
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

includes = ['encodings', 'encodings.*', 'glob',
            'sqlite3', 'wx.lib.scrolledpanel',
            'wx.richtext', 'wx.lib.mixins.listctrl',
            'wx.lib.sized_controls', 'sqlalchemy']

excludes = ['pyreadline', 'difflib', 'doctest',
            'tarfile', 'pickletools', 'optparse',
            'pickle', 'cookielib', 'urllib',
            'Tkinter', 'email', 'tcl', 'Tkconstants' ]

py2exe_options = {
    'build': {'build_base': 'dist/'},
    'py2exe': {
        'compressed': 1,
        'dll_excludes': ['msvcp90.dll', 'w9xpopen.exe'],
        'optimize': 2,
        'includes': includes,
        'excludes': excludes,
        'dist_dir': 'dist',
        'ascii': False,
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the error occur when you run `setup.py py2exe`?

Comment: yes, do you have any idea?

Comment: Verify that sqlalchemy is not installed as a zipped egg.

Comment: you are right, I figured it out! thx!

Comment: I originally installed SQLAlchemy using 'easy_install SQLAlchemy' and got the same error when using py2exe for my program.  When I upgraded SQLAlchemy using pip, it removed the error after typing in 'pip install SQLAlchemy --upgrade'

Answer (score 0):

Try including `sqlalchemy` in `packages` too

```
py2exe_options = {
    "packages": ["sqlalchemy.databases.sqlite"]
}
```

obviously I'm guessing that you're interested in `sqlite`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with sqlite. It's the way that sqlalchemy installed. However, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That usually works for me. Put the next line into your main script you tell `py2exe` to compile.

```
import sqlalchemy
```

Even though in general `py2exe` is rather greedy and includes much more than needed, sometimes it does just the opposite and skips needed packages despite the fact you list them in `includes`. Manually importing them usually works. Just put a comment next it to why you import packages you don't need in this module.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that SQLAlchemy is installed in an egg on your system; you need it to be unzipped, or to teach py2exe to read eggs. For a detailed overview, see [the py2exe wiki page ExeWithEggs](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ExeWithEggs).

That said, the easiest approach is to reinstall SQLAlchemy unzipped:

```
easy_install --always-unzip sqlalchemy
```